# Trying to restart iterating a loop from the very beginning once condition the same loop finished first iteration

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have 2 nested "for loops" , I'm trying to restart the first loop to iterate from the beginning, once its nested loop finished it's iterations successfully as per the if statement.
If however the nested loop meets the "else" condition, the outer loop should continue regularly it's iterations.
I'm trying to tell the code, that if the keywords_on_screen found start with the keyword created till that point to keep going, else to change latter at the last index where they stopped matching.

This is what I have already tried, but the first (outer)loop keeps continuing iterating trough the letters, rather then restart from beginning.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
keyList = ['a','b','c','d']
mainUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/"
browser.get(mainUrl)
searchInput = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
searchInput.clear()
keyword = str()

# I WANT THE LOOP TO RESTART FROM HERE ONCE THE NESTED LOOP IS FINISHED

for keyChar in keyList:
    searchInput.send_keys(keyChar)
    time.sleep(2)
    searchSoup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    searchResult = searchSoup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'suggestions-template'})
    results = searchResult[0].find_all('div', attrs={'class':'s-suggestion'})
    keyword = keyword + keyChar
    print("This is the keyword so far:>>>>   ",keyword)
    time.sleep(2)

    for data_result in results:
        data_keywords = BeautifulSoup(str(data_result),"html.parser")
        keywords_on_screen = data_keywords.find("div", class_="s-suggestion")["data-keyword"]
        print(keywords_on_screen)

        if keywords_on_screen.startswith(keyword):
            print('ALL GOOD')
        else:
            print('Condition not met, moving on next letter')
            continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are wanting is to continue the outermost loop, if the `else` condition in the nested loop is met. And if the `else` condition isn't met, then restart the outermost loop from the beginning.

**TRY:-**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
keyList = ['a','b','c','d']
mainUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/"
browser.get(mainUrl)
searchInput = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
searchInput.clear()
keyword = str()
ctr = 0
x = 0

# I WANT THE LOOP TO RESTART FROM HERE ONCE THE NESTED LOOP IS FINISHED

while x < len(keyList):
    keyChar = keyList[x]
    searchInput.send_keys(keyChar)
    time.sleep(2)
    searchSoup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    searchResult = searchSoup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'suggestions-template'})
    results = searchResult[0].find_all('div', attrs={'class':'s-suggestion'})
    keyword = keyword + keyChar
    print("This is the keyword so far:>>>>   ",keyword)
    time.sleep(2)

    for data_result in results:
        data_keywords = BeautifulSoup(str(data_result),"html.parser")
        keywords_on_screen = data_keywords.find("div", class_="s-suggestion")["data-keyword"]
        print(keywords_on_screen)

        if keywords_on_screen.startswith(keyword):
            print('ALL GOOD')
            ctr = 1
        else:
            print('Condition not met, moving on next letter')
            ctr = 0
            continue
    if ctr is not 1:
        x += 1
```

The outermost loop will execute infinitely until the nested `if` condition is met, else if the condition does not met then the outermost loop will execute normally and will terminate once all the elements of the list `KeyList` are exhausted.